# Quisiera conocer cuál es la fórmula o desarrollo estadístico que aplica fit_transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, inteligencia-artificial, scikit-learn

Es un ejemplo donde estoy usando **fit_transform** Este es un método de StandardScaler el cuál pertenece a la librería de Scikit Learn:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['01/02/2020',1,2,3,4,'03/02/2020',5,6,7,8,'02/02/2020',9,10,11,12,'04/02/2020',12,13,14,15]).reshape(4,5),columns=['Date', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'])
df = df1.sort_values(by='Date')
df2 = df.drop('B', axis=1)
df['Date'] = [parser.parse(x) for x in list(df['Date'])
df.index = df['Date']
df = df.drop('Date', axis=1)
ab = pd.to_numeric(df['D']).pct_change()
sc =  StandardScaler()
ab2 = sc.fit_transform(ab.values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Como indica la [documentación oficial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html). `StandardSclaler()` se utiliza para estandarizar tus datos basandose en la media y la desviación típica de tu distribución. Utiliza la siguiente formula:

```
z = (x - u) / s
```

Donde:

- `x`: es cada dato a estandarizar
- `u`: es la media de la variable
- `s`: es la desviación típica de la variable

Cuando se aplica el método `.fit_transform()` lo que hace es computar esta formula y **transformar tus datos y retornarlos** para que así queden estandarizados.

Answer (score 1):

Scikit Learn es una librería de código abierto, puedes ver todo el código en https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn

Como ya te han indicado, también tienes la documentación en la [página oficial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) donde buscar la función que deseas.

Además, en la documentación, junto a cada clase o función que se describe, tienes un enlace que te lleva al código en GitHub, por lo que cuando lees sobre cada función que te interese, puedes ir directo al código y leer cómo lo hace.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso, puedes ir a la clas [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) función [`fit_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform) y leer la descripción, los parámetros que recibe, lo que devuelve. Y a la derecha de la definición del método tienes el botón `[source]` que te lleva al [código fuente de esa función](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b3ea3ed6a/sklearn/base.py#L671).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]